# Phone gap keeps going back to index.html after resume

Tags: html, cordova, cross-platform, onresume, home-button

I have created an application using phonegap, this application contains many pages, I have a problem after pressing home button and then go back to the application thew application is reset to index.html page and loosing the state when I left the application.
I tested with Android so far.

Comment: show code that you are having issue with please.

Comment: Are you doing anything to handle pause and resume events, also agree we will need to see code to help. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.pause.html

Comment: No, i didn't add anything to handle pause and resume

Comment: Can you post actual application code?